# SQL update select with if

Tags: sql

I want to update my table with the value of another table. But when it does not find the value, then I want to insert 999.

How can I do that ?

```
UPDATE [ORDRE]
SET [LIB_TOURNE] = (SELECT TOP 1 LIB_TOURNE
                    FROM TOURNE
                    WHERE LE_COMMUNE like ORDRE.VILLE 
                      AND (TYPE_TOURNE = datepart(dw,getdate()) OR 
                           TYPE_TOURNE = 0) 
                      AND (datepart(hh, HEURE_TOURNE) = datepart(hh, ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR)))
```

That means if the select syntax can not find the value, then I will use the value 999 instead.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I think this statement updates all the records in ORDRE table. You probably should add a where statement to determine which records you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` (SQL Server) or `NVL` (Oracle) wrapped around your `SELECT` statement to check if it is returning `NULL` or no rows and then it will move to the value supplied.

```
UPDATE [ORDRE]
SET [LIB_TOURNE] = COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 LIB_TOURNE
                                FROM TOURNE
                                WHERE LE_COMMUNE LIKE ORDRE.VILLE
                                    AND (TYPE_TOURNE = datepart(dw, getdate())
                                        OR TYPE_TOURNE = 0                  )
                                    AND (datepart(hh, HEURE_TOURNE) = datepart(hh, ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR))
                            ), 999)
```

Also, depending on the size of your tables, there may be a more effiecient way to get the correct value of `LIB_TOURNE`.

Comment: COALESCE is the best answer here , its ANSI-SQL.

Comment: @sagi it can depend on what you are doing, `COALESE` handles multiple argument, and is slightly less efficient than the single checks for `ISNULL` and `NVL`.

Comment: I know that, I meant for this question because he didn't tag his RDBMS, so you can't provide a product specific answer . @WyattShipman

Comment: @WyattShipman: sagi is right, COALESCE is ANSI. If we read the body of query getdate() is a Tsql function (so I suppose our OP use Sql Server)